# Ubuntu 16.04 Wirelress Not Working

Tags: wireless, atheros, 16.04

I have AR9565 Aetheros Wireless and for an unknown reason, after I installed the OS (with the internet cable plug in all the time) the Wireless is not working. I have to restart it without the cable connected to connect to it.

Here are the info about my Wireless Card & everything I think: http://pastebin.com/2FQJQquD

It's frustrating.

Comment: The network diagnostics output is incomplete. Did you upload all of it to Pastebin? Please [run the network diagnostics](//askubuntu.com/a/425205/175814) again and [edit] your question to include a new link to the result.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

(originally posted by praseodym)

echo "blacklist acer_wmi" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf

and reboot

.. sprang into life listing available networks from the network icon (top right)